# validate numbers by limitation in length and true decimal format

Tags: validation, numbers, decimal

I want to validate numbers by regular expression.
My valid numbers are:

```
123456789012345.123
```

or

```
123.9
```

or

```
0.686`
```

Before decimal point must be 1 to maximum 15 numbers and after it must be maximum to 3 numbers; and negative numbers is optional.

invalid numbers are:

```
0.0
0.00
0.000
000
097654
05978.7
.657665
5857.
```

I found this regex but I can,t set numbers length limitation:

```
 ^-?(([1-9]\d*)|0)(\.0*[1-9](0*[0-9])*)?$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself

```
^-?(([1-9])([0-9]{1,14})?|0)(\.[0-9]?[0-9]?[1-9])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of * use {a,b} where a is the minimum number of preceding and b the maximum. Omit a or b for no minimum / maximum.

Comment: when I edit top regex to limit before decimal point to accept only 15 digits, it
 can not be match 

^-?(([1-9]\d){1,15}|0)(\.0*[1-9](0*[0-9])*)?$